# Have I configured my endpoints correctly for my react and node app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, nodemailer

I am trying to configure a node/express and react app with nodemailer and I can't seem to be getting emails sent. All the data is being sent to the node backend perfectly, however I can't seem to get an email sending through nodemailer. There is no error message on the console and I am not gettting any feedback from the smpt.transporter function on the console log. I was wondering if someone could help me out here? Much appreciated!

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PageOne from "./components/PageOne";
import PageTwo from "./components/PageTwo";
import PageThree from "./components/PageThree";
import PageFour from "./components/PageFour";
import PageFive from "./components/PageFive";
import PageSix from "./components/PageSix";
import { Button } from "semantic-ui-react";
import "semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css";

import axios from "axios";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      generalDetails: "Text",
      fName: "Text",
      mName: "Text",
      LName: "Text",
      gender: "Text",
    };

    this.onContentChange = this.onContentChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmitForm = this.onSubmitForm.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <PageOne handleChange={this.onContentChange} />
        <PageTwo handleChange={this.onContentChange} />
        <PageThree handleChange={this.onContentChange} />
        <PageFour handleChange={this.onContentChange} />
        <PageFive handleChange={this.onContentChange} />
        <PageSix handleChange={this.onContentChange} />

        <Button onClick={this.onSubmitForm}>Submit Form</Button>

        <br />
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }

  onSubmitForm = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = {
      generalDetails: this.state.generalDetails,
      fName: this.state.fName,
      mName: this.state.mName,
      lName: this.state.lName,

    };


    axios
  .post("http://localhost:5000/home", data)
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result)
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log("Something went wrong. Please try again later");
  });


  };

  //end

  onContentChange(fieldname, data) {
    console.log("On Content Change", data);

    this.setState({
      [fieldname]: data
    });
  }
}

export default App;
```

Server.js

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
const path = require('path')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 5000
const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json())
// to support JSON-encoded bodies

app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({

    // to support URL-encoded bodies
    extended: true
  })
)



app.get('/home', (req, res) => {
  console.log(
    'Hello from .get /home',
    req.body.generalDetails,
    req.body.firstName,
    req.body.mName
  )
})


const http = require('http');



app.post('/home', (req, res) => {

  var server = http.createServer(app)
  server.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Express is running on port 3000')
  })


  app.post('/home', function (req, res) {
      var data=req.body;

      var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
         service: "Gmail",
         auth: {
         user: "email",
         pass: "pass"
         }});

     smtpTransport.sendMail({  //email options
     from: "email",
     to: "email", // receiver
     subject: "Emailing with nodemailer", // subject
     text:req.body.generalDetails,
     html: "here your data goes"// body (var data which we've declared)
      }, function(error, response){  //callback
           if(error){
             console.log(error);
          }else{
             console.log("Message sent: " + res.message);
         }

     smtpTransport.close();
      }); });

  let data = [{
    //page one data
    generalDetails: req.body.generalDetails,
    fName: req.body.fName,
    mName: req.body.mName,
    lName: req.body.lName,
    email: req.body.email,


   }];

   res.json(data);

 }

);

app.listen(port, () => `Server running on port ${port}`);
```

Comment: Is your endpoint getting hit? If you log something under the Express POST route, does it get logged?

Comment: @rb612 could you show me how to do that if you don't mind? I am just quite new! Thanks

Comment: sure - just add a  `console.log(“Some text”);` after `var data = req.body` and see if that gets logged when you restart the server and do the appropriate action that should trigger it.

Comment: Yeah it didn't show up so it looks like its not hitting, would you know what would be the next steps?Thanks for that!

Comment: okay that’s a somewhat good sign. You do see the “express is running on port 3000” yes?

Comment: Yeah I see the "express is running on port 3000" 

and the status 200 says its ok too if that helps

Comment: ah, huge issue: you have an `app.post` call nested within another. There you should not have two `app.post(‘/home’` routes.

Comment: hmm, thanks yeah, I removed that now i am getting a 500 internal error from my axios request

Answer (score 0):

Since youa using Gmail make sure set the Access for less secure apps setting to Enable
Go to : https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps to do it. In your code there seemes to be two routes with same name /home (both post endpoints). Why are you listening to server twice?. try this code.

```
    const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
    const path = require('path')
    const express = require('express')
    const app = express()
    const http = require('http');
    const server = http.createServer(app)
    const port = 5000
    const cors = require('cors')
    app.use(cors())
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    app.use(bodyParser.json())
    // to support JSON-encoded bodies

    app.use(
      bodyParser.urlencoded({

        // to support URL-encoded bodies
        extended: true
      })
    )



    app.get('/home', (req, res) => {
      console.log(
        'Hello from .get /home',
        req.body.generalDetails,
        req.body.firstName,
        req.body.mName
      )
    })


   app.post('/home', function (req, res) {
          var data=req.body;

          var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
             service: "Gmail",
             auth: {
             user: "email",
             pass: "pass"
             }});

         smtpTransport.sendMail({  //email options
         from: "email",
         to: "email", // receiver
         subject: "Emailing with nodemailer", // subject
         text:req.body.generalDetails,
         html: "here your data goes"// body (var data which we've declared)
          }, function(error, response){  //callback
               if(error){
                 console.log(error);
              }else{
                 console.log("Message sent: " + res.message);
             }

         smtpTransport.close();
          }); });

      let data = [{
        //page one data
        generalDetails: req.body.generalDetails,
        fName: req.body.fName,
        mName: req.body.mName,
        lName: req.body.lName,
        email: req.body.email,


       }];

       res.json(data);

     }

    );

    app.listen(port, () => `Server running on port ${port}`);
```

Comment: thanks, now I am getting a 500 internal error from my axios request it seems

Comment: **req.body.email** you dont have email field in the data you pass from the front end. that might be the issue. and also check for the console for errors

Comment: I do, I just took it out because data would have been to long haha.